# Optmized/Resized png images to store in directory /assets android

Tags: android, optimization

I need to store Png images in assets directory of my android application
Everything takes place locally , without having a remote server .
There are methods or libray, to be used to optimize / resize images in order to decrease their weight ?

Answer (score 0):

1. If its icons or app's asset..you could use [photoshop](http://www.photoshop.com/) and save image as "optimized for web"
2. You could segregate images to different screen densities refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754523/is-there-any-tool-which-can-a-resize-png-image-into-a-image-for-ldpi-mdpi-hdp)  and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
3. You could use [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to load images in async to reduce the load on main thread

Comment: Thanks, but I think library like optipng, pngcrush, because the sizes of images are fixed.